# Why does Back button in Internet Explorer IE 11 not work in StackOverflow?

Tags: internet-explorer

If I click the back button in IE when I am browsing in stackoverflow, I see the earlier website web address for a second and but the web address reverts back to stackoverflow. I assume this is the same for everything in StackExchange. Why is that and how do I fix? Looking for an explanation, way to diagnose and possible solution - not go use another web browser.

Comment: Both the back and the foreward buttons work here  in IE11 (and other browser).Maybe give an example of the starting address from which you were linked?  A question which you departed from ?  and the exact train of events to follow to reproduce this?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a cached redirection problem (it works for me so I can't reproduce to check). Try it from an InPrivate tab (e.g. using Ctrl+Shift+P). If that works, try clearing the browsing history from the original tab (Tools > Internet Options).

It could also be a problem with a cache elsewhere, a virus or virus scanner problem, a popup blocker, a DNS problem...

Some trial and error with different browsers and different computers might be necessary to get to the bottom of this.